# Null pointer in middle of nowhere

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So I've got a fragment which contains a hidden map and a visible listview that is populated from data I get from a backend API. Suddenly out of nowhere I got a fatal crash that points nowhere in my code. The crash occurs somewhere after the listview is created.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12800)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15400)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:5242)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15397)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15397)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at  com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:815)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15397)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3147)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15397)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2567)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2869)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2782)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2188)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've done quite a bit of work since last running the app, and I'm not certain what's causing it. I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me at where I could start looking.

If you need more information I'll gladly provide it.

Thanks a whole heap, I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: is Spinner related ?

Comment: @blackbelt Possibly. I am using a dialog fragment with a progressbar spinner at the center that pops up and disappears to prevent users from touching the UI while I request data from the network. Could a dialog fragment cause this?

Comment: spinner has no scrollbar. Are you somewhere/somehow calling scrollbar related methods?

Comment: @PG_Android I would, but not sure what to show, the project is significantly large with many components. If you have seen an issue like this before, could you point me to what might cause this? I would be glad to submit any code related to your suspicions

Comment: @blackbelt Not directly. The listview has a scrollbar enabled, however I've tried disabling it and it still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

After a gruelling few hours wasted on this problem, it turned out to be a library which removed listview "glow" on overscroll.

The specific function was:
AbsListView.setSelector(int resID) and the library was passing in an ID referring to a colour rather than a drawable which was required.

Thanks a lot for the people who helped, I really appreciate any thought given to this problem.
I hope this helps anyone in future.